# remove python multiline comments and do not remove string

Tags: python, shell, sed, comments

the question: I want to use shell scripts to remove:

```
"""
111
222
"""
or 
'''
111
222
'''
```

but do not remove

```
s = """
111
222
"""
```

I test the following ways:

```
find -name *.py | xargs -i  sed -i "/^\s*\"\"\".*\"\"\"$/d" {}

find -name *.py | xargs -i sed -i '/"""/,/"""/d' {}
```

but i have no idea about

```
s = """
111
222
"""
```

please help

the test code like this,thanks 
>
    """
    template
    class Foo {
    public:
    virtual int Bar();
    };
    """

```
source = """
class Foo {
public:
virtual int Bar();
};
"""

"""
template<class T>
class Foo {
public:
virtual int Bar();
};
"""

source = """
class Foo {
public:
virtual void Bar(bool flag) const;
};
"""

source = """
class Foo {
public:
virtual int Bar(void);
};
"""
```

uptonow:
the 
"""
aaa
"""
and the
="""
bbb
"""
have been test ok
function delete_multiline_comments

```
function delete_multiline_comments
        grep -n '\"\"\"' gmock_class_test.py | sed  '/=/,+1d' >a.txt

        line=$(wc -l a.txt| awk '{print $1}')

        for (( i=0;i<$line/2;i++ ))
        do
                second=`tail -1 a.txt | tr -cd "[0-9]"`
                sed -i '$d' a.txt

                first=`tail -1 a.txt | tr -cd "[0-9]"`
                sed -i '$d' a.txt

                sed -i "${first},${second}d" gmock_class_test.py
        done
end
```

the following line used to remove """XXXX""" and '''XXX''' line

```
sed -ie "/'''.*'''/d" 
sed -i  "/^\s*\"\"\".*\"\"\"$/d"
```

Comment: You are better off not abusing string literals as comments.

Comment: LFG1000554173:/usr1/r00230944/temp_i # cat gmock_class_test.py

"""
template<class T>
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual int Bar();
};
"""


    source = """
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual int Bar();
};
"""
LFG1000554173:/usr1/r00230944/temp_i # sed -e '/[^=]\s*"""/,/"""/d'  gmock_class_test.py

"""
template<class T>
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual int Bar();
};
"""

Comment: I have discuss with my colleague：the """ always come with a pair, then we can test the 1,3,5,7....from the grep """ result and grep = used -v, and then

Comment: post the example input content with all kinds of entries

Comment: """
template<class T>
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual int Bar();
};
"""

    source = """
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual int Bar();
};
"""

"""
template<class T>
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual int Bar();
};
"""

    source = """
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual void Bar(bool flag) const;
};
"""

    source = """
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual int Bar(void);
};
"""

Comment: @chepner,the code was written by others, my work is to remove the comments,  i'm surprising about the python's mechanisms comments

Comment: Be careful if you try something with grep, since (your example, first line), a comment using `"""` doesn't always correspond to multiple lines. Do you want it to be shell or can it be a python script?

Comment: @Nuageux,thanks, Not only single line, may be multiline, but i have the ways to deal with it, like this:find -name *.py | xargs -i  sed -i "/^\s*\"\"\".*\"\"\"$/d" {}

Comment: Please edit all that additional information readably into your question and delete the comments which thereby become obsolete.

Comment: @Yunnosch,Because of more and more situations discovered when test script , that is why more and more commens added

Comment: @Nuageux, my task is to remove comments of shell, python and ruby, and then used shell to handle them, so...

Comment: Hi @Jason, I got it working, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sed, but you can try [vims](https://github.com/MilesCranmer/vim-stream/).

For your problem, this is a quick way to do it (it swaps the """ with a key: eh3UgT):

```
cat myfile.py | \
    vims -e '=\s*"""' 'f\"xxxaeh3UgT\<esc>/\"\"\"\<enter>xxxaeh3UgT' \
            '"""' 'V/\"\"\"\<enter>d' -t '%s/eh3UgT/"""/g'
```

It works for me on your test file!

Explanation:

1. `'=s\*"""'` - Match all lines with `=` and then `"""` somewhere after
2. `'f\"xxxaeh3UgT\<esc>/\"\"\"\<enter>xxxaeh3UgT'` - On that match, move to the first `"` with `f\"` (a vim command), then delete the quotes `xxx`, then enter insert mode `a`, then type `eh3UgT`, then move to the next triple quotes `\<esc>/\"\"\"\<enter>`, then delete them `xxx`, then type the key again `a` then `eh3UgT`.
3. `'"""'` - Match all remaining triple quotes
4. `'V/\"\"\"\<enter>d'` - Start highlighting `V`, move to next triple quotes `/\"\"\"\<enter>`, then delete `d`.
5. `-t '%s/eh3UgT/"""/g'` - Turn on normal vim command-line mode, replace all keys with triple quotes

Here, 1. and 2. act to "save" the string variables by replacing their quotes with a key, then 3. and 4. delete everything contained within triple quotes, then 5. replaces the key back with the triple quotes.

If you are worried about the key `eh3UgT` being matched elsewhere by accident, just make it longer. If you are worried that this is insecure (say this is a recurring script), then randomly generate the key each time.

Comment: thanks, when i exe vims command locally,  my local bin dir do not have vims, and i search with google , i can not get the answer...., can you please rewrite the method with shell? my OS is SUSE12.2

Comment: You can run: `wget -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MilesCranmer/vim-stream/master/vims && chmod +x vims`. Then, just run my command with `./vims` instead of `vims`.